# Rounded corner & elliptical shape button in HTML

Tags: html

I want to create a HTML button with rounded corner and elliptical shape without image.
What is the way to do it?

Comment: With CSS3: http://www.google.com/search?q=css3+rounded+corners

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This makes all sides rounded:

```
border-radius:40px;
```

This makes them elliptical:

```
border-radius:40px/24px;
```

Have a look here to see:

http://jsfiddle.net/xnTZq/

Or with some extra ugly fanciness:

http://jsfiddle.net/xnTZq/6/

Comment: It works,But as soon as i provide any background color like background-color:#39C ,it makes corner rectangle.

Answer (score 3):

```
-webkit-border-radius:3em / 1em;
-moz-border-radius:3em / 1em;
border-radius:3em / 1em;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#box-1 {
   -webkit-border-radius:10px;
   -moz-border-radius:10px;
   -border-radius:10px;
}
```

This box should have a rounded corners for Firefox, Safari/Chrome, Opera and IE9.

This is a very useful article to read if you need more help with this:

http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/

Comment: It works,But as soon as i provide any background color like background-color:#39C ,it makes corner rectangle.

Comment: Just FYI, you didn't mark your CSS code as code when you entered it, hence the funny formatting of your post. Try using the code icon (looks like this: {}) next time.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly use css3 border-radius and keep the height small to get an elliptical shape, good site to use for cross browser support (browsers that support css3 only of course unless you use css3 pie http://css3pie.com/ )  http://border-radius.com/

koolies